# how to use count with condition without using group by in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

```
select   bcd from bcd22 where bcd=@bcd1 group by bcd  having count(bcd)%2=0

cmd22.Parameters.Add("@bcd1", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "bcd").Value = textBox1.Text;
```

---

**input set:**
      1000,1001,1003,1000

---

corresponding **OUTPUT:**

```
1001
1003
1000
1000
```

---

whereas I want the output to be as

```
1000
1001
1003
1000
```

**without grouping**

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How is the title related to the question? why without group by? please be more specific with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Based on your responses to my answer below, this looks like an issue with your c# code, not your SQL. Can you show how you're adding those query results into your gridview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870152/how-to-auto-scroll-bar-  grid-view-after-inserting-updating  the above link shows how im displaying on grid

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the output you're getting and the output you want are the same thing, with the exception of the order, and there's no guaranteed order for a query like the one you posted.

If you want a specific order, you can achieve that by adding an `ORDER BY` clause, but it's hard to provide much specific help on that without more information. For example, it looks like you want the output to be in the same order as the input, but I'm not quite clear where those input values are coming from. All I see is a single parameter in your query.

Comment: the inputs are obtained from texbox1.text and is matched with the the value present in the database.

Comment: And you're passing multiple inputs with that single parameter? That doesn't seem right to me; maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: i have a database with all the bcds stored ex 1000,1001 and so on and i have a form with a grid view and and a text box , whenever i enter a bcd into text box its matched with database and its displayed on grid view in first row of gridview. Later when i give the second input as 1001 it gets displayed in second row of grid view later when i give 1000 as input instead of displaying the 1000 in third row the first 1000 is rearranged from 1st row to second row .I want the first 1000 should not change row after second time input of 1000 .